# Como ler o cabeçalho IPTC de uma imagem através do C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, imagem

Qual a melhor forma de ler o cabeçalho IPTC de uma imagem ?

Tenho a seguinte imagem e precisava ler a descrição dela(para um banco de imagens), porém já pesquisei muitas formas que para mim ficaram meio confusas.

Alguém já fez isso e sabe me dizer o melhor caminho? Estou utilizando o ASP.NET MVC (C#). Segue a o que eu quero ler na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A meu ver, [`System.Windows.Media.Imaging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.aspx):

```
var stream = new FileStream("arquivo.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
var metadata = decoder.Frames[0].Metadata as BitmapMetadata;
if(metadata != null)
    var dados = metadata.Keywords;
```

---

Uma abordagem mais recente usa a [ExifLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExifLib/), obtendo os dados EXIF, que implementam o IPTC:

```
using (ExifReader reader = new ExifReader(@"arquivo.jpg"))
{
    // Os dados estão em `reader`.
}
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET).

Comment: Cigano, eu tentei usar essa biblioteca Media.Imaging, ele não consegue encontrar o media, preciso fazer referência ? ou baixar alguma dll?

Comment: É pra estar no Assembly do .NET `System.Windows`.

Comment: Ele parece não estar atribuindo nada ao metadata, erro: "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto", tentei debugar tudo mas mesmo assim ele não referencia nd ao metadata.

Comment: Coloquei mais um exempo. Veja se atende.

Comment: Cigano, 10min antes de eu ver seu post tinha encontrado o ExifLib, valeu ! Com esse da certinho, provavelmente mais para frente quando eu aperfeiçoar meu conhecimento na linguagem e em como tudo funciona terei que desenvolver algo próprio, mas até o estado atual do projeto, o ExifLib está ótimo.